# Android < 2.3.7 shortcuts

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

In android 2.3.7 and older when I long click on the screen the menu shows a list of shortcuts. Is there an option to add my own shortcut to this list?

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not possible. Only apps and the Android system can install shortcuts and widgets on your home screen.